# Second query in a set not returning results

Tags: mysql

Can anyone see any reason why the second result set here produces 0 results even though if I run the queries independently the second one *will* return results??

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(mu.ID)) AS users
FROM `companies` c
JOIN `companysites` cs ON c.ID = cs.companyID
JOIN `users` mu ON cs.ID = mu.siteID
JOIN `targetcategories` tcat ON c.smTargetCategory = tcat.ID
WHERE isVendor = 0;

SET @in = "users";

SELECT *
FROM privileges
WHERE userID IN (@in);
```

I actually need the 2nd query to be a delete query but want to check results before I do it.

Comment: Are you using mysql prepared statement to execute the above query ?

Comment: How do you run your queries?

Comment: Thanks I will be running them with PHP probably as one query or multiple. The issue is that I actually need the second query to be a delete query which I don't believe is possible seeing as its from the same table. I should have probably explained that in the question!

Answer (score 0):

Pass your first query in a sub-query, for delete:

```
DELETE FROM privileges
WHERE userID IN (
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(mu.ID)) AS userID
  FROM `companies` c
  JOIN `companysites` cs ON c.ID = cs.companyID
  JOIN `users` mu ON cs.ID = mu.siteID
  JOIN `targetcategories` tcat ON c.smTargetCategory = tcat.ID
  WHERE isVendor = 0
);
```

If mysql return error, you can try to 'encapsulate' your subquery:

```
DELETE p.*
FROM privileges p
WHERE userID IN (
    SELECT userID
    FROM 
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(mu.ID)) AS userID
        FROM `companies` c
        JOIN `companysites` cs ON c.ID = cs.companyID
        JOIN `users` mu ON cs.ID = mu.siteID
        JOIN `targetcategories` tcat ON c.smTargetCategory = tcat.ID
        WHERE isVendor = 0) x);
```

Comment: The issue is that I actually need the second query to be a delete query which I don't believe is possible seeing as its from the same table. I should have probably explained that in the question! Apologies

Comment: On which tables you want delete ? On which tables is your query ?

Comment: The second query should be DELETE FROM privileges WHERE userID IN (@in);